# Bash script get/extract specific info/word from output info

Tags: ubuntu, grep

the command `nvcc --version` outputs the following:

```
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2019 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Wed_Oct_23_21:14:42_PDT_2019
Cuda compilation tools, release 10.2, V10.2.89
```

I'm trying to get the cuda version which in this case is `10.2` from the 4th line.

Therefore i tried the following:

```
cudaVersion="$(nvcc --version| grep 'Cuda compilation ')"
echo "$cudaVersion"
```

this gives me however the whole line as an output. However i just want to assign the version to `cudaVersion`

I believe this must work with `cut`, however i can't get it

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your shown samples, could you please try following. Written and tested in GNU `grep`.

```
nvcc --version | grep -oP '^Cuda compilation.*release \K[0-9]+\.[0-9]+'
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
nvcc --version |  ##Running  nvcc --version command and sending its output to grep command.
grep -oP          ##Using grep command using -P option for enabling PCRE ERE here.  
'^Cuda compilation.*release \K[0-9]+\.[0-9]+'
                  ##Checking if line starts Cuda compilation till release space.
                  ##\K will skip till matched value(since we don't want in output) dot and digits.
```

---

---

OR with any `awk`:

```
nvcc --version | 
awk '
  /^Cuda compilation.*release / && match($0,/release [0-9]+\.[0-9]+/){
    print substr($0,RSTART+8,RLENGTH-8)
}
'
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
nvcc --version |      ##Running command nvcc --version sending output to awk here as input.
awk '                 ##starting awk program from here.
  /^Cuda compilation.*release / && match($0,/release [0-9]+\.[0-9]+/){
                      ##Checking condition if line starts from Cuda compilation till release AND using match function to release space digits dot digits here.
    print substr($0,RSTART+8,RLENGTH-8)  ##printing sub string with matches value and printing Only version here.
}
'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```sh
cudaVersion="$(nvcc --version | awk '/Cuda compilation/{sub(/,$/,"", $5); print $5}')"
```

Here, the lines (record) is split into fields with whitespace and the line with `Cuda compilation` is searched for, and once found, prints Field 5 value without trailing comma.

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/rmaqSu):

```sh
s='nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2019 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Wed_Oct_23_21:14:42_PDT_2019
Cuda compilation tools, release 10.2, V10.2.89'
awk '/Cuda compilation/{sub(/,$/,"", $5); print $5}' <<< "$s"
## => 10.2
```

See a test performed on a GPU instance:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Either i'm not implementing your code correctly or its not working for me. I copied exactly the line above cudaVersion...., and then printed cudaVersion. it retuns nothing

Comment: Hi, Sorry for the late answer. I've tried it as well it still doesn't work, despite the fact that it seems a lot obvious to me  However, thanks alot for the help.

Comment: @k.jbaili You can see a screenshot from my GPU instance, it works.